# PHP $_POST Array Empty

Tags: php, arrays, session

i'm new in coding and have a problem coding on Mac.

When i do var_dump($_POST), answer is: array(0){}

Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name=strip_tags($_POST["name"]);
    $age=$_POST["age"]*1;
    $_SESSION["name"] = $name;
    $_SESSION["age"] = $age;
}
else {
    $name = $_SESSION["name"];
    $age = $_SESSION["age"];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Session demonstration</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Session demonstration</h1>
<a href="session-2.php">Demo session</a><br>
<a href="session_destroy.php">Close session</a><br><br>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>"
      method="post">
    Your name is:
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>"><br>
    You are:
    <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $age?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if ($name and $age) {   
    if ($name and $age) {
        echo "<h1>Hello, $name</h1>";
        echo "<h3>You are $age</h3>";
    }
    else {
        print "<h3>Bye!</h3>";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Same time, when i press submit button it shows me:

Notice: Undefined index: name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP_Course 2/demo/mod2/sessions/session-1.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: age in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP_Course 2/demo/mod2/sessions/session-1.php on line 6

Maybe someone knows what can i do.

Sincerelly

Comment: add method=post in your form element

Comment: But it is there ...

Comment: @jevgeni_serstjukov Post is there and nothing is wrong with it. What is the purpose of adding two if condition. Secondly, you get those errors, when the session is empty.

Comment: Maybe instead of this `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` you should use something like `if(isset($_POST["name"]))`

Comment: sorry my bad the problem with this is your session variables are not set `$_SESSION["name"]` and `$_SESSION["age"]`

Comment: @Hackerman Just tried, but when i do var_dump($_POST) array is still (0)

Comment: can't understand anything

Comment: `<php` should be `<?php`

Comment: Maybe you should start with the basics... http://www.dummies.com/programming/php/

Answer (score 1):

the problem with this is your session variables are not set at the beginning and you are trying to assign your $name and $age with those unassigned variables on your else block. Validate your assignments like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $age = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST["name"]);
    $age = $_POST["age"] * 1;
    $_SESSION["name"] = $name;
    $_SESSION["age"] = $age;
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['name']) || isset($_SESSION['age'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['age'])) {
        $age = $_SESSION['age'];
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Session demonstration</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Session demonstration</h1>
        <a href="session-2.php">Demo session</a><br>
        <a href="session_destroy.php">Close session</a><br><br>
        <form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
            Your name is:
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"><br>
            You are:
            <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $age ?>"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
<?php

    if ($name and $age) {
        echo "<h1>Hello, $name</h1>";
        echo "<h3>You are $age</h3>";
    } else {
        print "<h3>Bye!</h3>";
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried. But after var_dump($_post) = array(0){}

Comment: There was some errors before try it now. And var_dump($_POST) **UPPER CASE** and var_dump after you submit the form.

Comment: after i submit the form it gives me: 
Notice: Undefined index: name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP_Course 2/demo/mod2/sessions/session-1.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: age in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP_Course 2/demo/mod2/sessions/session-1.php on line 6

Comment: Do you have `$name = $age = "";` on your third line??

Comment: yes i do. And the same thing. Maybe something is with my php.ini?

Comment: Ok copy and paste whole code above I just edited and try to run as a seperate file

Comment: Unfortunately: 


Notice: Undefined index: name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP_Course 2/demo/mod2/sessions/session-1.php on line 5


Notice: Undefined index: age in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PHP_Course 2/demo/mod2/sessions/session-1.php on line 6

Comment: hi put `var_dump($_POST);` after this line `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` post the result

Comment: As always: array(0) { }

Comment: try action="" in your form element I think you have problem with $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]